# How can one interpret just by seeing the equation of parabola that it opens UP/DOWN and or centered around $x$- or $y$-axis.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

How can one interpret just by seeing the equation of parabola that it opens UP/DOWN and or centered around $x$- or $y$-axis.

I know parabola equation as $ax^2+bx+c$, I know that it opens up when $a>0$ and down when $a<0$, but I am not sure to about the orientation of parabola over $x$- or $y$-axis.

For example - how could I have interpreted that $y =x^2-2$ will open up and is oriented on $y$-axis.

My biggest doubt is how can $-2$ in $y=x^2-2$ can help in revealing that the parabola equation is centered around $y$-axis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For equations $y=ax^2+bx+c=0$ , the axis of parabola is parallel to $Y$ axis... Vice versa for the other form of equation. And for negative values of $a$ , the parabola would have a maximum value at a particular point...

Comment: Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Are you asking about [determining the axis of symmetry of a parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#As_a_graph_of_a_function)?

Answer (score 1):

> how can $-2$ in $y=x^2-2$ can help in revealing that the parabola equation is centered around $y$-axis.

The short answer is: it cannot. The $-2$ has nothing to do with finding the axis of the parabola.

If your parabola has an equation of the form $y = ax^2 + bx + c,$
you find the axis of the parabola by looking at the coefficients $a$ and $b.$
Specifically, the axis will be the line $x = -\frac{b}{2a},$ because
$$
ax^2 + bx + c = 
a\left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 + \left(c - \frac{b^2}{4a}\right).
$$

When the particular parabola you have to deal with is $y = x^2 - 2,$ then in terms of the usual $a,b,c$ form of the equation you have $a = 1,$ $b = 0,$ and $c = -2.$
Therefore $-\frac{b}{2a} = 0$ and the axis is the line $x = 0,$
that is, the $y$-axis.

Alternatively, you could simply observe that $y = x^2 - 2$ is just the parabola
$y = x^2$ shifted downward $2$ units.
Since $y = x^2$ has $x = 0$ as its axis, so does $y = x^2 - 2.$
(It only went downward, not sideways.)